# How to mock AddMilliseconds() or (object) casting in C#/EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, mocking

I have a SQL Server database with the following table:

```
StartDate: date (null)
EndDate: date (null)
PreferredFromMs : bigint (null)
PreferredToMs : bigint (null)
```

The start/end datetimes are calculated on the SQL Server side (date part + time part (stored as milliseconds) because it is saved separately)

The query is working fine in app (EF Core 7) but when I try to Mock it in unit tests, it fails with

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.Int64'

```
var data = query
               .Where(r => routeStart <= ((DateTime)(object)r.EndDate.Value).AddMilliseconds(r.PreferredToMs == null ? 0 : (long)(object)r.PreferredToMs.Value)                     
                           && routeEnd >= ((DateTime)(object)r.StartDate.Value).AddMilliseconds(r.PreferredFromMs == null ? 0 : (long)(object)r.PreferredFromMs.Value))                
               .ToList();
```

These (object) castings look suspicious, but they are necessary:

1. EndDate is `date` that does not have a time part. Without time calling `AddMilliseconds()` fails as Linq-to-entities cannot translate the expression correctly (requires `datetime` not `date`)
2. PreferredToMs is `bigint` and cannot be used directly (as TimeSpan) because the expression is translated as `DATEPART(millisecond, [r].[PreferredToMs]) AS bigint)`
   `DATEPART()` is unable to handle `bigint` and is causing

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities

I am setting the mock like:

```
IQueryable<Data> _fakeData = new List<Data>(1) { _myData }.AsQueryable();
```

```
mock.Mock<IMyRepository>().Setup(x => x.Query()).Returns(_fakeData);
```

How do I setup that (object) or (long) casting correctly?

Or should I mock the `AddMilliseconds()` ?

Comment: Do you know `?.`? or `??`

Comment: Also you are doing null check for bigint and not for date.... Why?

Comment: why should you want to mock anything here? Just provide a fake repo that gets you some fake `DateTime`.

Comment: Fake repo is provided by IQueryable<Data> _fakeData --- this contains List<Data> casted as .AsQueryable();

Comment: So why do you want to mock the `DateTime`? Faking the repo *and* its data is pretty odd.